# Google Sheet CountIFs and Grouping

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to group Data dynamically through a formula in google sheets. I am not using PivotTables as I want to add additionally columns on the result table. Is there a way through a custom formula I will be able to achieve a grouped list in Column (E) from my source Data Column (A) which show the number of Y and N values for each Symbol in column (A). Please refer to image. I tried with a CountIFS, but had little luck. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Image Attached]

Answer (score 3):

Try `=QUERY(A2:B11, "select A, count(A) group by A pivot B", 1)` in E2

**Reference:**

- Sheet's [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Edit 2: Answer with Formulae in every cell.

Use this formula in E3 and then drag to E3:F4 to count the number of Y & N for A & B.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$11, $D3, $B$3:$B$11, E$2)
```

Use this formula in G3 and then drag to G3:G4

```
=IFERROR(E3/F3, E3)
```

This way you can filter the resulting table and sort it by any column.

[image]

If this works for you please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks @AkshayNayar. This works, however, if I add a column of my own on the resulting data, I am not able to sort in ASC or DESC based on the new column. Can you let me know how that can be done?

Comment: Can you share a completed sample of what you want the sheet to look like?

Comment: Here is the image to what I would like to achieve https://imgur.com/a/TxvKki9

Comment: You can try this updated formula:

=QUERY(QUERY(A2:B11, "select A, count(A) group by A pivot B order by A asc", 1), "select Col1, Col3, Col2, (Col3/Col2) order by (Col3/Col2) desc label (Col3/Col2) 'Y/N' ", 1)

It won't be able to tackle the IFERROR case you have mentioned in your screenshot, but it won't throw an error either.

Comment: Thanks for that. Another question, If I use a Pivot Table instead of a query. I can achieve what I want. However, I want to add another Col3/Col2 from the resulting Pivot Table Data and sort that in Ascending order. Is that possible? Is there a way to have another sheet just transform from the Pivot Table into values into another sheet based on a formula?

Comment: I tried to manually add a column to the Pivot Table (resulting table) and if I click on sort A -Z or Z-A it automatically undos it